# WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked

Tags: android, multithreading

I have four a sync task which are executing from `onCreateView()` of fragment those thread are retrieving data from server, inside each four threads there are more than 15 threads for getting images from server. at that time GC block my four threads for more than 1&half minutes... all four `async` task at `preExecute()` method they are working fine... but at `doInBackground()` its block for more than 1 minute.

Thanks in Advance..........

```
 03-20 19:48:19.250: D/dalvikvm(6416): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
 03-20 19:48:21.020: E/Image(6416): 1
 03-20 19:48:21.760: D/dalvikvm(6416): GC_EXPLICIT freed 112K, 8% free 26454K/28551K,                  
 03-20 19:48:23.489: D/dalvikvm(6416): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
  03-20 19:48:26.749: D/dalvikvm(6416): GC_EXPLICIT freed 81K, 7% free 26605K/28551K,     paused 66ms+23ms, total 3256ms
 03-20 19:48:28.010: E/Image(6416): 2
 03-20 19:48:28.470: D/dalvikvm(6416): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
 03-20 19:48:31.220: D/dalvikvm(6416): GC_EXPLICIT freed 76K, 7% free 26762K/28551K,  paused 26ms+25ms, total 2751ms
 03-20 19:48:32.760: D/dalvikvm(6416): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
03-20 19:48:35.020: E/Image(6416): 1
 03-20 19:48:35.369: D/dalvikvm(6416): GC_EXPLICIT freed 75K, 6% free 26918K/28551K,     paused 49ms+44ms, total 2610ms
 03-20 19:48:36.950: D/dalvikvm(6416): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
 03-20 19:48:39.690: D/dalvikvm(6416): GC_EXPLICIT freed 77K, 6% free 27074K/28551K, paused 43ms+24ms, total 2660ms
03-20 19:48:41.240: D/dalvikvm(6416): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
 03-20 19:48:42.020: E/Image(6416): 2
 03-20 19:48:43.860: D/dalvikvm(6416): GC_EXPLICIT freed 75K, 5% free 27231K/28551K, paused 71ms+48ms, total 2615ms
 03-20 19:48:45.740: D/dalvikvm(6416): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
03-20 19:48:48.641: D/dalvikvm(6416): GC_EXPLICIT freed 76K, 5% free 27388K/28551K, paused 37ms+46ms, total 2901ms
 03-20 19:48:49.031: E/Image(6416): 1
```

03-20 19:48:50.240: D/dalvikvm(6416): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
   03-20 19:48:52.950: D/dalvikvm(6416): GC_EXPLICIT freed 77K, 4% free 27543K/28551K,  paused 49ms+44ms, total 2708ms
    03-20 19:48:54.550: D/dalvikvm(6416): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms

Code to download image...

public class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask{

```
private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

private final WeakReference<ProgressBar> progreeBarReferance;

public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    progreeBarReferance=null;
}

public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView, ProgressBar progressBar){
    progreeBarReferance= new WeakReference<ProgressBar>(progressBar);
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    if(progreeBarReferance != null){
        ProgressBar progressBar=progreeBarReferance.get();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}

@Override
// Actual download method, run in the task thread
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
    return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
}

@Override
// Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (isCancelled()) {
        bitmap = null;
    }

    if(progreeBarReferance != null){
        ProgressBar progressBar=progreeBarReferance.get();
        if(progressBar != null){
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }


    if (imageViewReference != null) {
        ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {

            if (bitmap != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

            }
        }

    }
}

static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode
                    + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
            return null;
        }

        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                System.gc();

                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                return bitmap;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or
        // IllegalStateException
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
    }  catch(Throwable e){

        Log.e("From Throwable", "");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }finally {
        if (client != null) {
            client.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

On One Fragment there is Four list-view. each `listview` working on separate `asynctask` each list item calling `ImageDownloaderASynctask`

Code to set Image on list-view item
Below code is same for all four `listview` adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_swaps_item, null);


    }
    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_swap_item_ImageView_image);
    TextView title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_swaps_item_textview_title);
    ProgressBar progressBar=(ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_swaps_item_progressBar);

    title.setText(followersList.get(position).first_name);

    new ImageDownloaderTask(imgIcon,progressBar).execute(followersList.get(position).imageUrl);

    return convertView;
```

`async` task for getting data from server for four list view on single fragment

```
    public class GetProfileDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    private String[] ids;
    private String[] params;
    private JMYSwapsList jmySwapList;
    private int flag;
    private JMyFriendsList jmyFriendsList;
    private JMyFollowerList jMyFollowerList;
    private JProfileList jProfileList;

    public GetProfileDataAsyncTask(String[] ids, String[] params, int flag) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.ids=ids;
        this.params=params;
        this.flag=flag;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        Log.e("0", "1");
        if(flag==0)
        {
            mySwapProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if(flag==1){
            myFriendProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if(flag == 2){
            myFollowersProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if(flag == 3){
            friendRequestProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        Log.e("0", "2");
    //  System.gc();
    }



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.e("1", "1");
        if(flag == 0){




            String response= Profiles.getDataFromServer(ids, params, Constants.My_SWAP_URL);

            Log.e("2", "1");
            jmySwapList=Profiles.parseMySwap(response);

            if(jmySwapList != null){
                if(jmySwapList.Success != null){
                    for (JSwap jSwap: jmySwapList.Success) {
                        System.out.println("from do Person  "+ jSwap.name);
                        mySwapList.add(new MySwapsData(jSwap.name,"http://"+ jSwap.swap_image_thumb.replace("\\","").replace(" ", "%20")));
                    }
                }else{
                    if(jmySwapList.noData != null){
                        Log.e("Profile From My Swap", jmySwapList.noData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Log.e("1", "2");
        if(flag == 1){

            String response= Profiles.getDataFromServer(ids, params, Constants.MY_FRIENDS_URL);
            Log.e("2", "2");
            jmyFriendsList=Profiles.parseMyFriends(response);

            if(jmyFriendsList != null){

                if(jmyFriendsList.Success != null){

                    for (JFriend jFriend: jmyFriendsList.Success) {
                        System.out.println("from do Person  "+ jFriend.first_name);
                        myFrindsList.add(new FriendAdapterData(jFriend.first_name,"http://"+ jFriend.user_image_thumb.replace("\\","").replace(" ", "%20")));
                    }

                }else{

                    if(jmyFriendsList.noData != null){
                        Log.e("Profile From My Friends", jmyFriendsList.noData);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        Log.e("1", "3");
        if(flag == 2){
            String response= Profiles.getDataFromServer(ids, params, Constants.MY_FOLLOWERS_URL);
            Log.e("2", "3");
            jMyFollowerList=Profiles.parseMyFollowers(response);

            if(jMyFollowerList != null){

                if(jMyFollowerList.Success != null){
                    for (JFollower jFollower: jMyFollowerList.Success) {
                        System.out.println("from do Person  "+ jFollower.user_id);
                        //  myFrindsList.add(new FriendAdapterData(jFollower.user_id,"http://"+ jFriend.user_image_thumb.replace("\\","").replace(" ", "%20")));

                        myFollowerList.add(new FollowerAdapterData(jFollower.first_name,"http://"+ jFollower.user_image_thumb.replace("\\","").replace(" ", "%20")));
                    }
                }else{
                    if(jMyFollowerList.noData != null){
                        Log.e("Profile From My Follower", jMyFollowerList.noData);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        Log.e("1", "4");
        if(flag == 3){

        }

        if(flag == 4){
            String response= Profiles.getDataFromServer(ids, params, Constants.GET_PROFILE);
            jProfileList=Profiles.parseProfile(response);
            if(jProfileList != null){
                if(jProfileList.Success != null){
                    for(JProfile jProfile: jProfileList.Success){
                        System.out.println("from do Person  "+ jProfile.first_name);
                    }
                }else{
                    if(jProfileList.noData != null){
                        Log.e("from Profile", jProfileList.noData);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //MySwaps
        if(flag==0){
            mySwapAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mySwapProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        //Friends
        if(flag==1){
            myFriendAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            myFriendProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        //Follower
        if(flag == 2){
            myFollowerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            myFollowersProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        //Friend Rquest
        if(flag == 3){
            friendRequestProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if(flag == 4){
            String imageUrl=null;

            if(jProfileList != null){
                for(JProfile jProfile: jProfileList.Success){
                    //System.out.println("from do Person  "+ jProfile.first_name);
                    //  imageUrl=jProfile.user_image_thumb;
                    imageUrl="http://"+ jProfile.user_image_thumb.replace("\\","").replace(" ", "%20");
                }
            }
            if(imageUrl != null)
            {
                new ImageDownloaderTask(myProfileImage).execute(imageUrl);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If you can post your code, we can get the overview. But it looks like you are using too much memory.

Comment: Note that if you are using AsyncTask in API 13 (Honeycomb) and above, AsyncTask will execute sequentially instead of parallel. My guess is one of the threads is hogging the resources thus causing GC to take place. Check your threads again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the line:

```
new ImageDownloaderTask(myProfileImage).execute(imageUrl);
```

to the:

```
new ImageDownloaderTask(myProfileImage).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, imageUrl);
```

It allow your tasks to run on different threads.

Second problem is: `System.gc();`
Why are you ising it? In normal situation (and downloading an image definitely is not a rocket sicence) Garbage collector should be run only by system, not by user.

Comment: Thanks.... now its working fin............. also i have one problem...  when i am scrolling list view its again downloading already downloaded image.... is this issue is because of i am executing async task in getView method.....???\

Comment: yes, getView method in ListView is called every time when list item is show on the list. http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html